# Check if hostname is in an array with JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, hostname

Why does this code doesn't work ? (it is part of a chrome extension),

I don't understand why using this method to check if the hostname of the current page is in the array *ac_websites* does not work.

I am not sure what *window.location.hostname returns* (string or something else)

Maybe *indexOf()* only works with strings.

```
const ac_websites = ["sciencedirect.com", "ncbi.nlm.nih.gov", "pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov", "ieeexplore.ieee.org", "ci.nii.ac.jp"]


chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request) {
    const url = document.location.href
    const hostname = window.location.hostname
    
    if (ac_websites.indexOf(hostname) != 1) {
        window.open("https://google.com/" + url);
    } else {
        alert("Not an academic website")
    }
})
```

Comment: `hostname` returns a string. Maybe the hostname begins with `www.`? You don't have that in your `ac_websites` array.

Comment: You need to check if `indexOf` is `!= -1` not `!= 1`

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `Array.includes()`.

```js
if (ac_websites.includes(hostname)) {
        window.open("https://google.com/" + url);
    } else {
        alert("Not an academic website")
    }
```

Comment: No need to answer a typo question, even if this is good advice. Use a comment instead, please.